# RESTful name for the method that does two operations

Tags: rest, restful-url

In the API I have tickets resource and there are 2 methods:

1) Get the ticket status (ticket can be locked/unlocked)

```
GET /api/tickets/:id
```

2) Update the ticket status

```
PUT /api/tickets/:id with status=locked|unlocked
```

What I need - is to combine the status check with the actual update in one API call. And I also need to know if the status was changed with the API call or it was already set to needed value. E.g:

```
ticket_status = "unlocked"
PUT /api/tickets/:id/check_lock
changes ticket_status to "locked" and responses with "success"

ticket_status = "locked"
PUT /api/tickets/:id/check_lock
ticket_status is already "locked" so we response with "ignored"
```

For reverse operation we can have

```
PUT /api/tickets/:id/check_unlock
```

I understand that we are breaking the single responsibility principle here by combining to operations but this is done to decrease number of API requests and this is going to be called very frequently.

So I'm looking for good names instead of those ugly "check_lock", "check_unlock" as they seem to be rather ambiguous.

Comment: Why do you need "status check" when locking an already locked ticket or unlocking an unlocked one seems to pose absolutely no problem? Idempotence is a great way to just not care about this.

Comment: This is a simplified example. I have a queue of tickets to handle. If the ticket is locked I need to delay processing it and push it to the tail of the queue. So I need to know if it was locked or not.

Comment: If the ticket is locked, do you update the resource anyway (does the PUT succeed) or is the operation aborted?

Comment: When the ticket is "unlocked" we update it and return response with modified=true in it. If the ticket is "locked" we don't make any changes and return response with modified=false. Decided to follow the approach with POST /api/tickets/:id/toggle_lock advised by andih.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using something like

```
PUT /api/tickets/:id/check_lock
```

to update the lock status is not recommended (as not to say bad practice).
When reading `check_something` one usually thinks of a method that is safe i.e. one *does not* expect it to modify any value.

Your example `PUT` is not idempotent. i.e. invoking PUT two times on the same resource results in different outcomes. Which contradicts the [HTTP Specification for PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)

> PUT request is defined as    replacing the state of the target
> resource.

In your case it's best to use `PATCH` to update part ticket resource as described in [RFC5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) or even  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902

```
PATCH /api/tickets/:id/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

{ "op": "replace", "path": "/lock", "value": "unlock"  }
```

You may choose to an ETag in your response to signal whether the resource has been modified or not.

Or just the HTTP Status Code 200 with a message body in which you return whether the resource was modified or not and also the new value of the lock state.

If you want to toggle the lock status you should use something like which is called "action resource". In this case use `POST`.

```
POST /api/tickets/:id/toggle_lock
```

As result you can return the new lock status and whether it was updated or not as part of the body of the HTTP 200 Status Code.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking in resources I would not have a operation check_unlock.
I would suggest: GET /api/tickets/:id with the status of the ticket in the json answer. Even if you have two http calls.

Or if the status results in an error, you can answer with an error 400 or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a slightly different approach and use the `409 Conflict` status code.

> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current
>   state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where
>   it is expected that *the user might be able to resolve the conflict* and
>   resubmit the request.

Successful session :

```
PUT /api/tickets/123 { ... locked: true ... }
200 OK
```

Already locked session :

```
PUT /api/tickets/123 { ... locked: true ... }
409 Conflict
POST /api/ticket-queue { // ticket data here }
201 Created
```